# How can I find p2, while I only have p1, angle and distance units

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

Image would probably be best

[image]

My goal is to find future step for a player in a game I am making. The player is at (x1, y1) and is walking distance is 7 and the direction/angle is 53.  What would be its next point(x2, y2)?

How can I find point2 (x2, y2) on a graph if I have: angle/direction and the distance to go?

Here's what i tried so far:

```
x1 =-5;
y1 = -3;
x2 = 7;
y2 = 5;
r = 7;
deltaY = y1 - y2;
deltaX = x1 - x2;

/* Finding the angle */
angleInDegrees  = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI;

/* Finding destination point (x2,y2) */
desTx = r * Math.cos(angleInDegrees)+x1;
desTy = r * Math.sin(angleInDegrees)+y1;
```

You can also check the fiddle I made at :http://jsfiddle.net/chLTK/7/

You can see the line is not in the right direction - in a ideal situation the green line will continue with the same direction of the p1 and p2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i find point2(x2,y2) on a graph if i have: angle/direction and
>   the distance to go?

You can try:

```
/// angle in radians
function lineToAngle(x, y, length, angle) {

    var x2 = x + length * Math.cos(angle),
        y2 = y + length * Math.sin(angle);

    return [x2, y2];
}
```

If you input a calculated angle first then change the way you calculate deltas to:

```
deltaY = y2 - y1;
deltaX = x2 - x1;
```

`Math.cos()` and `Math.sin()` needs the angle in radians so don't convert the `atan2()` result to degrees:

```
angleInRadians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

desTx = r * Math.cos(angleInRadians)+x1;
desTy = r * Math.sin(angleInRadians)+y1;
```

Comment: Just tried didnt change check http://jsfiddle.net/chLTK/9/ I've update the changes

Comment: @NetaMeta If you calculate angle first then try to switch x1-x2 to x2-x1 etc. in your deltas. Math.cos/sin must have the angles in radians so no need to convert atan2 result to degrees first

Comment: played with those, did not produce the desired results

Comment: bahh on the radians didnt realize !! Thanks this works.